# Async await and setTimeout are not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

You can see what I've done [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/142nvnly03).

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const asyncFunc = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve("Gotcha!!!"), 10000);
  });
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: "Fetching..."
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const text = await asyncFunc();
    this.setState({ text });
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.state.text}</div>;
  }
}
```

The app should show `Fetching...` first, then shows `Gotcha!!!` after 10 seconds. But, it's not working. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is:

```
setTimeout(resolve("Gotcha!!!"), 10000);
```

The first argument to `setTimeout` should be a *function*. At the moment, you're *calling* `resolve` immediately as `setTimeout` tries to resolve its arguments (synchronously). Instead, pass it a function that *then* calls `resolve`:

```
setTimeout(() => resolve("Gotcha!!!"), 10000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(resolve, 10000, "Gotcha!!!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `setTimeout` a callback function, change it to this

```
setTimeout(() => resolve("Gotcha!!!"), 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const asyncFunc = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Gotcha!!!"), 10000);
  });
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "Fetching..."
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const newText = await asyncFunc();
    this.setState({ text: newText });
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.state.text}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```